# Why compiler warns about implicit conversion in setprecision?

Tags: c++

When I compile the following code, compiler gives me the warning:

```
"Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'std::streamsize' (aka 'long') to 'int'".
```

I'm a little bit confused about this warning since I just try to save the current value of the precision to set it back to the original value later.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::streamsize prec = std::cout.precision();
  std::cout << std::setprecision(prec);
}
```

What is the right way to save the precision value and set it back later in this case?

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I get no warnings or errors with `g++ -O3 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic`

Comment: What compiler? I think that `std::streamsize` on your implementation is `signed long`, while `setprecision` takes a signed `int`.

Comment: @Prashant: Than it must be clang, Visual Studio, Borland, Intel C, etc.

Comment: Exactly why C++11 re-introduced the `auto` keyword for auto-deducing the variable's type from expressions. Otherwise your code looks correct to me...

Comment: I also get no warnings or errors when using `clang++` with the same compiler flags, but mine is `Apple clang version 2.1 (tags/Apple/clang-163.7.1) (based on LLVM 3.0svn)`

Comment: @Prashant I get warnings with `g++ -Wall -Wextra -Wconversion`

Comment: @YePhIcK `auto` is how I *generated* this warning years later: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56013850/why-is-there-a-type-inconsistency-in-stdstream-manipulator-infrastructure?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It looks like it's just an oversight in the standard specification.

`ios_base::precision` has two overloads, one that gets and one that sets the precision:

```
// returns current precision
streamsize precision() const;

// sets current precision and returns old value
streamsize precision(streamsize prec) const;
```

So this code will not give you warnings:

```
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::streamsize prec = std::cout.precision(); // gets
  std::cout.precision(prec); // sets
}
```

However, the `setprecision()` function simply takes a plain old `int`:

```
unspecified-type setprecision(int n);
```

and returns an unspecified functor, which when consumed by a stream `str` has the effect of:

```
str.precision(n);
```

In your case, `streamsize` is not an `int` (and does not have to be), hence the warning. The standard should probably be changed so that `setprecision`'s parameter is not `int`, but `streamsize`.

You can either just call `precison()` yourself, as above, or assume `int` is sufficient and cast.

```
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
  std::streamsize prec = std::cout.precision();
  std::cout << std::setprecision(static_cast<int>(prec));
}
```

*Edit: [Apparently it was submitted to be fixed and reached no concensus (closed as not-a-defect)](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/lwg-closed.html#1148).*