# Why is there a type inconsistency in std::stream manipulator infrastructure?

Tags: c++, types, iostream, std

Doing a little stream output today and needed to forcibly format a field.  Recalling that most of the manipulators are persistent I decided to insure against shenanigans:

```
auto oldp = std::cout.precision(); // Cache this to be able to undo a set
std::out << "threshold" 
         << std::setprecision(2) << m_threshold   // set 
         << std::setprecision(oldp) << std::endl; // restore
```

and my linter throws a warning about in implicit integer down-conversion on the "restore" line.

A little poking around and 'sure'nuf, `std::setprecision` takes `int`, while `std::ios_base::precision` returns `streamsize` (which is a `long` on the system in front of me).

So the linter is making a valid complaint (and it is easy enough to make it go away), but *why* does this state of affairs exist?

Comment: *::sigh::* It's not like I didn't search.